# What does it mean to use full web editor on the filesystem/network?

Tags: html, web-services, editor, visual-web-developer

Hello I am a junior web developer and I sometimes when the projects are too large, I take them home and work on them. I was asked by my supervisor to use a full web editor on the filesystem/network. Can someone explain to me what it is and how should I go about it?

Comment: I think you really should have sought clarification from your supervisor. Also, why is this tagged with "Visual Web Developer" and "Web Services"?

Answer (score 0):

The best advice is: If you don't understand, ASK!

> "Better to ask a thousand stupid questions than do a single stupid thing".

We need to break this down. Which bits don't you understand?

- "full web editor" - generally refers to using a desktop editor such as Visual Studio, Brackets or Atom. As perhaps opposed to a hosted editor.
- filesystem - where the files are stored on your PC
- network - where the files are stored not on your PC